# How to have rounded corners for stage or layers in React Konva

Tags: reactjs, konvajs

[image]

Hi ,

I want my stage to look like below image and user will draw  on it , my question is how can I do this with React-Konva ? 
I only saw cornerRadius property in rect. 
And also users actions should be with in the stage.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with CSS styles:

```
  <Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight} style={{
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
    borderRadius: '15px',
    overflow: 'hidden'
  }}>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/98on17x8xr

Comment: Thank you very much  , I require one more thing . I need to avoid users going over the border too.. I have missed that part in the question , I ll update it

Answer (score 2):

you can provide `cornerRadius` key attribute to Rect object

Comment: let demo = new Konva.Rect({
      x: 10,
      y: 20,
      width: 48,
      height: 64,
      fill: 'gray',
      cornerRadius: 5,         // <----- do the trick 
    })

Answer (score 1):

The CSS solution is simpler, but if you want to do it with Konva there is a clipping function you can use.

https://konvajs.github.io/docs/clipping/Clipping_Function.html